Django Autocomplete Light Foreign Key not rendering
I believe I have tried everything but still my field is not rendering. My objective is to be able to find products writing their names. I tried to followed this tutorial: https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html#tutorial
My diferent files are like this:
models.py:
# Product class
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sku = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default=get_default_category)
    availability = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=[('E', 'Existent'), ('O', 'On demand')])
    price = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

# Sales orders class
class SaleID(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()

class Sale(models.Model):
    ID = models.ForeignKey(SaleID, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    total_price = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Sale of {self.quantity} {self.product.name} for {self.total_price}"

forms.py:
from dal import autocomplete

# Add Product Form to add products
class SaleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    product = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Product.objects.all(), widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='product-autocomplete'))
    quantity = forms.IntegerField(required=True, widget=forms.NumberInput(attrs={"placeholder":"Enter quantity", "class":"form-control"}), label="")

    class Meta:
        model = Sale
        fields = ("product", "quantity")  # Define the fields to include from the Product model
        exclude = ("user", "ID", "total_price")

SaleModelFormSet = modelformset_factory(Sale, form=SaleForm, extra=1, can_delete=False)

views.py:
# SALES ADD    
def add_sale(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == "POST":
            saleid_instance = SaleID.objects.create(date=timezone.now())
            sale_formset = SaleModelFormSet(request.POST)  # Create instance of SaleFormSet
            if sale_formset.is_valid():
                saleid_instance.date=timezone.now()

                for sale_form in sale_formset:
                    if sale_form.cleaned_data.get('product') and sale_form.cleaned_data.get('quantity'):    # Check it has product and quantity
                        # Assign the ID to the sale before saving
                        sale_form_instance = sale_form.save(commit=False)
                        sale_form_instance.ID = saleid_instance # Assigning saleID to the form
                        sale_form_instance.total_price = sale_form_instance.product.price * sale_form_instance.quantity
                        sale_form.save()

                messages.success(request, "Sales added successfully")
                return redirect('home')
        else:
            sale_formset = SaleModelFormSet(queryset=SaleID.objects.none())  # Create instance of VariantFormSet
        return render(request, 'website/add_sale.html', {'sale_formset': sale_formset})  # Pass variant_formset to template
    else:
        messages.warning(request, "You must be logged in to do that")
        return redirect('home')
    
#Product autocomplete with dal:
class ProductAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):
    # Don't forget to filter out results depending on the visitor !
    def get_queryset(self):
        print("hello")
        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return Product.objects.none()
       
        qs = Product.objects.all().order_by('name') 
        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(name__icontains=self.q)
        return qs

My urls.py:
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    path('add_sale/', views.add_sale, name='add_sale'),     
    path('product-autocomplete/', ProductAutocomplete.as_view(), name='product-autocomplete'),
    ...
]

When I go to URL/product-autocomplete, it gives me the list of the products
{"results": [{"id": "3", "text": "Conejo", "selected_text": "Conejo"}, {"id": "1", "text": "Casa", "selected_text": "Casa"}, {"id": "2", "text": "Madera", "selected_text": "Madera"}], "pagination": {"more": false}}

My base.html
<!-- Loads Bootstrap Framework -->
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
{% load static %}

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Inventory Management System</title>

  <!-- Include DAL JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Include Font Awesome CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- Include Bootstrap 5 CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static 'website/favicon.ico' %}">
  
</head>

I believe the problem is in my add_sale.html. I implemented this tutorial: https://medium.com/all-about-django/adding-forms-dynamically-to-a-django-formset-375f1090c2b0 to have multiple forms (my idea is to add multiple products to the same sale).
So my add_sale.html looks like this:
{% extends 'website/base.html' %}
{% block content %}
{% load static %}

<h1>Add sale</h1>
 <!-- This code may have deprecated bootstrap: https://medium.com/all-about-django/adding-forms-dynamically-to-a-django-formset-375f1090c2b0 -->
<body>

    <form method="POST" action="{% url 'add_sale' %}">
        <!-- To avoid hackers -->
        {% csrf_token %}
        <!-- Variant formset -->
        {{ sale_formset.management_form }}
        {% for sale_form in sale_formset %}
        <div class="row form-row">
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    {{ sale_form.product}}
                    {{ sale_form.quantity}}
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success add-form-row"><i class="fas fa-plus fa-xs"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}

        <br>
        <button type="submit" class="btn custom-btn">Add Sale</button>
        <a href="{% url 'home' %}" class="btn btn-secondary">Back</a>
    </form>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js' %}"></script>

    {{ form.media }}

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>

        function updateElementIndex(el, prefix, ndx) {
            var id_regex = new RegExp('(' + prefix + '-\\d+)');
            var replacement = prefix + '-' + ndx;
            if ($(el).attr("for")) $(el).attr("for", $(el).attr("for").replace(id_regex, replacement));
            if (el.id) el.id = el.id.replace(id_regex, replacement);
            if (el.name) el.name = el.name.replace(id_regex, replacement);
        }
        function cloneMore(selector, prefix) {
            var newElement = $(selector).clone(true);
            var total = $('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val();
            newElement.find(':input:not([type=button]):not([type=submit]):not([type=reset])').each(function () {
                var name = $(this).attr('name').replace('-' + (total - 1) + '-', '-' + total + '-');
                var id = 'id_' + name;
                $(this).attr({ 'name': name, 'id': id }).val('').removeAttr('checked');
            });
            newElement.find('label').each(function () {
                var forValue = $(this).attr('for');
                if (forValue) {
                    forValue = forValue.replace('-' + (total - 1) + '-', '-' + total + '-');
                    $(this).attr({ 'for': forValue });
                }
            });
            total++;
            $('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val(total);
            $(selector).after(newElement);
            var conditionRow = $('.form-row:not(:last)');
            conditionRow.find('.btn.add-form-row')
                .removeClass('btn-success').addClass('btn-danger')
                .removeClass('add-form-row').addClass('remove-form-row')
                .html('<i class="fas fa-minus fa-xs" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
            return false;
        }
        function deleteForm(prefix, btn) {
            var total = parseInt($('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val());
            if (total > 1) {
                btn.closest('.form-row').remove();
                var forms = $('.form-row');
                $('#id_' + prefix + '-TOTAL_FORMS').val(forms.length);
                for (var i = 0, formCount = forms.length; i < formCount; i++) {
                    $(forms.get(i)).find(':input').each(function () {
                        updateElementIndex(this, prefix, i);
                    });
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
        $(document).on('click', '.add-form-row', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            cloneMore('.form-row:last', 'form');
            return false;
        });
        $(document).on('click', '.remove-form-row', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            deleteForm('form', $(this));
            return false;
        });
    </script>
</body>
{% endblock %}

Currently the add_sale page looks like this:

I don't know where the error is, and how to fix it :(.
Any help would be greatly appreciated it.
I have tried loading different js files, changing my add_sale.html but still my products are not show inside my product field.
